# Unique/useful combinations of a full name in a logical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

Imagine you have a person. His full name is Robert Jack Senior. I am trying to make a script searching with only useful combinations of his name in a logical order.

This means that I will first try to search with Robert Jack Senior, then Robert Senior then Robert Jack then Robert. This is the most logical order in my opinion. If you think otherwise let me know!

So far I have figured out how to get all unique combinations. However, in my opinion the script will take unnecessary long for searching all combinations even though this has higher accuracy.

So my question is: how do I exclude all the unnecessary combinations and put them in a logical order and do you agree with me removing combinations?

The reason I am asking this is because a full name can also consist of just a first name and last name. So no middle name. The code must be consistent with these variations. Unfortunately, I could not think of a solution yet.

My code:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

fname = 'Robert Jack Senior'
fname = fname.split(' ')
all_subsets = list(chain(*map(lambda x: combinations(fname, x), range(1, len(fname) + 1))))
all_subsets = [' '.join(subset) for subset in all_subsets]
print(all_subsets)
```

Output:

```
['Robert', 'Jack', 'Senior', 'Robert Jack', 'Robert Senior', 'Jack Senior', 'Robert Jack Senior']
```

As discussed before the desired output (again, in my opinion) would be:

```
['Robert Jack Senior', 'Robert Senior', 'Robert Jack', 'Robert']
```

Comment: What do you mean by **how do I exclude all the unnecessary combinations**? Is the output not your desired output?

Comment: @Errol no its not. I will update my question so this will be more clear

Comment: `split(" ")` can be written `split()`, splitting on whitespace is the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code always base the order and combination on the first name given `name_split[0]` which is ***Robert*** in this case. Try this:

```
name = 'Robert Jack Senior' 

def get_name_combinations(name):
    name_split = name.split()
    return [' '.join(name) for i in range(len(name_split) + 1) for name in combinations(name_split, i) if name and name[0] == name_split[0]][::-1]

print(get_name_combinations(name))
```

output:

```
['Robert Jack Senior', 'Robert Senior', 'Robert Jack', 'Robert']
```

Comment: `split(" ")` can be written `split()`, splitting on whitespace is the default.

Answer (score -2):

What if you do the following: 
Firstly search with the normal name, if no results are found then go on with the combinations.

Hope this helps.

Best, Ismail